# How to get SECONDARY STORAGE name in Android?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I need to get the name of sd-card storage like Android document picker shows.
[android document picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTSWk.jpg)

It shows two storages:

1. Internal storage (which original name is "primary"; its real path is `/storage/emulated/0/`)
2. 9C33-6BBD (SD-Card of my device, its real path is `/storage/extSdCard/`)

I can get the path of secondary storage using:

```
System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); //returns /storage/extSdCard/
```

But how can I get its name (9C33-6BBD) programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
try it...

First get All files in list

```
var file=new Java.IO.File("storage/");
var listOfStorages=file.listFiles();

var isSDPresent=false;
if(listOfStorages[1].Name.Contains("emulated")||listOfStorages[0].Name.Contains("-"))
{
   isSDPresent=true;
   var sdCardName=listOfStorages[0].Name;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually verified this works? I corrected the errors I could without testing it.

Comment: @AbandonedCart it was 2 year back ,I don;t remeber perfectly, but we did tested this and used that time.

Comment: Alright. Hopefully the typos were the only difference between what is here and what was tested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory().name()
```